# Dropdown Changing Session Value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working out of codeigniter and trying to find out how I can change the value of a session variable when the user changes a dropdown menu.

```
<select name="testselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean have a value pre selected?

Comment: No I have the value preselected already however if the user selects a different option in the dropdown I want it to be able to change the session global again.

Comment: Look, you need to give more information; must something happen after the user changes the dropdown value that must happen before they submit the form? If so, then you need to use JavaScript to capture this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with **jQuery**, I'm presuming you're using it somewhere in your page, so you change your HTML to this:

```
<select name="testselect" id="testselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

and add this to your `$(document).ready( .. );` call to capture changes to that dropdown like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testselect').change(function() {
        // POST the changed value to a method in a controller that can accept
        // a parameter and that'll set the session variable for you
        $.post("http://location/to/controller/method/",
          { testselect: this.value },
          'html'
        ); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use JavaScript to submit the news value and also you need a function in the controller that will catch that value. But I'm not sure if its possible to change the session id. I'm almost sure its not possible, but surely unsafe.

Comment: Its not the session id its just a session key value

Comment: One thing is the session value and other is the key. What do you mean with session key value? Be clear.